# A "Fourier Phase" for (stationary) random processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, signal-processing

Let $X_t$ be a real w.s.s. random process. Its spectrum is given by $S(f)=\mathcal{F}R_X(\tau)(f)$ where $R_X$ is the process autocorrelation.
As $X_t$ is real, the spectrum will be real and symmetric.

In deterministic signals, we can perform the Fourier transform on the signal and obtain two functions: the amplitude and the phase. The amplitude shows the presence of various frequencies in the signal, whereas the phase indicates the 'locations', noncontinuities, etc.

However, in random processes, as we perform Fourier transform on the autocorrelation, we get only the sense of the Fourier amplitude.
Is there a measurement that can be performed in order to get some sort of "Fourier phase" for a random process?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to take the FT of the autocorrelation. There is no reason why you can't take the FT of the signal and then look at the resulting amplitude and phase. In fact, if $X(f)$ is the FT of the signal, then $X^\ast(f) X(f)$ will give you the same thing as the FT of the autocorrelation. On top of that, there are other transforms, e.g. the bispectrum and trispectrum, that use the phase of the signal rather than ignoring it.